# CRM 4.0 - Queue Stop Working

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a queue in a CRM 4.0 (4.0.7333),this queue receive e-mails from a job that works every 15 minutes,the problem is that the queue sometimes stops working,i need to restart the email router service in services.msc,after that the queue begin to work again,i searched everywhere but didn't find the root cause,someone know something about this problem?

Comment: Some debugging ideas: any error in the Event Viewer ? What about the Platform Trace ? Does the job itself write logs, if not *why*, if yes does it register anything odd ?

Comment: In my experience, the email router is terribly unreliable: it usually requires continuous monitoring, and needs periodic reboots.  Not that that helps you, but the issue is more common than you may think.  
That being said, there may still be an issue with your setup, Alex's questions should help you target the root cause.